# My pagination link is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Im new to CodeIgniter framework, and i am trying to use the pagination class. So then i have some trouble with it.

**Situation**
The display of data is okay. But the link for go to other page of the table it is not working. When i click the "1,2,3" button it is not going for other data. It is still in the same place.

**Question**
What is the main problem of my code?

My Controller :

```
public function view_all_staff() {
        if(!$this->user_auth_model->logged_in()) {
            redirect('user/login');
        } else {

            $config = array();
            $limit                = 1;
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->library('table');
            $uri_segment          = 4;
            $offset               = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);
            $config['base_url']   = base_url() . 'admin/view_all_staff';
            $admin = "Admin";
            $query                = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM admin where login_type = '".$admin."'");
            $config['total_rows'] = $query->num_rows();

            $config['per_page'] = $limit;

            $config['uri_segment']   = $uri_segment;
            $config['cur_tag_open']  = '<li class="active"><a href="' . base_url() . $this->uri->uri_string() . '">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $sel = $this->db->select('*');
            $sel = $this->db->where('login_type =', 'Admin');

            $records = $this->db->get('admin', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
            foreach ($records->result() as $item) {
                $q[] = $item;
            }
            $data['records']          = $q;
            $data['total_rows']       = $query->num_rows();
            $data['per_page']          = $limit;
            $data['uri_segment']      = $uri_segment;
            $data['create_staff_suc'] = $this->session->flashdata('create_staff_suc');

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('browse_staff_view', $data);
        }
    }
```

My View :

```
<tr><td colspan="5" style="margin-top: inherit; text-align: right;"> <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></td></tr>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                    <tr><td colspan="5" style="margin-top: inherit; text-align: center;"> <?php echo "No Records Found"; ?></td></tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
```

I hope someone can tell me what is the problem.

Comment: You aren't really providing any functional code. All you are providing is variable definitions and calls. No possible way of answering this. You don't even specify the programming language.

Comment: oh, im sorry for that. i am new to this site. i will try to make it much more clearer for you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$uri_segement` needs to be 3, not 4, based on your base_url only using 2 segments (`admin/view_all_staff`).